# how to definitively remove last commit from branch

Tags: git, commit, reset

I'm in the process of learning GIT. and I have a question. Namely, I created 4 commits, then I used the command "git reset HEAD ^" then i have:

1:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FDtx.png

then deleted unstaged files and my graph looks like:

2:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S4jV.png

and when i use command "git checkout 021aded19665ee1fb0bcee772ec8019d0b655776" commit D comes back

3:
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKBBp.png

My question is, is it possible to permanently delete a commit?

Comment: If there is no sensible data, you don't care and it will be garbage collected one day. Otherwise, have a look to `git gc`with some specific parameters to bypass the commits retained by the reflog. Search answers on the subject on Stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is it possible to permanently delete a commit?

No, and also yes.

More specifically, there is no Git command to *eject* an object from a repository.  There are only Git commands to *add* objects to a repository.  There is, however, a defined process by which *unused and unreferenced* objects may eventually be removed.

A safe way to be sure that a commit is no longer in a repository is to check to see if the hash ID of the commit is accessible as an object.  If not, the object is no longer in the repository.  Hence, you can:

- make the object *unreachable* (see [Think Like (a) Git](https://think-like-a-git.net/));
- use `git gc` with parameters that make it more aggressive in terms of removing such objects (see [the "checklist for shrinking a repository" section of the `git filter-branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository));

and then check to see if it's gone.  Or, more simply, you can copy the old repository to a new-and-improved repository using `git clone` and see if the unwanted objects have been left behind in the process.  Note, however, that if you introduce an "infected" repository that *does* contain the unwanted object to an "uninfected" repository, the unwanted commit is likely to ensconce itself happily in the previously-uninfected repository.  Commits are, in this way, like a highly communicable virus.

Some Git hosting sites (e.g., GitHub) will not expire an unreachable object just because it's unreachable.  In effect, they don't promise to run `git gc` at all.

This is why the answer is both yes and no: you can do it, indirectly; you can't do it directly; and you can't be sure that, having done it, you will be immune to reinfection later, unless you are sure you have stamped it out completely everywhere, or "vaccinate" your Git by adding something that makes sure the "bad" commit is never re-added.  (There is no built-in method for doing this last thing, although I think there probably should be.)